# Bootstrap 4 Forms With 2 Columns (Dynamic)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-4

I have a user registration form (Bootstrap 4 - in Razor Template)

I will hide some part of form depends on user fillings. My registration form has 2 step. Here is second step.

If user selects a country that hasn't states. I will hide states.

Here is the problem.

If I write code like [in here](https://www.codeply.com/go/JpGyYQ06fu/bootstrap-4-form-2-columns) when i hide states that part will be missing.

I wrote code like below using float-left. If I hide any part the other parts moves and fill the missing part.

```
<div class="container py-5 bg-warning">
<div class="row">
    <div id="register" class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
        <form asp-action="Create" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @if (@Model.StateList != null)
            {
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                    <label asp-for="State"></label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateList, @Model.StateList, "- Please Select -",
                        new {@class = "form-control"})
                    <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
                </div>
            }
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="City"></label>
                <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Phone"></label>
                <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Company"></label>
                <input asp-for="Company" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Company" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="TaxId"></label>
                <input asp-for="TaxId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TaxId" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Gender"></label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, @Model.GenderList, "- Please Select -",
                    new {@class = "form-control"})
                <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="AboutJob"></label>
                <input asp-for="AboutJob" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AboutJob" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="PostCode"></label>
                <input asp-for="PostCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PostCode" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Town"></label>
                <input asp-for="Town" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Town" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Address"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Celluar"></label>
                <input asp-for="Celluar" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Celluar" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="TaxOffice"></label>
                <input asp-for="TaxOffice" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TaxOffice" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="TaxAddress"></label>
                <input asp-for="TaxAddress" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TaxAddress" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="FullName"></label>
                <input asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Birthday"></label>
                <input asp-for="Birthday" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Birthday" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="CitizenId"></label>
                <input asp-for="CitizenId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CitizenId" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6 float-left">
                <label asp-for="Website"></label>
                <input asp-for="Website" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Website" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4 float-right">Kayıt Ol</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you know there is a span element for error messages under inputs. If I had an error this form looks bad. Do you have any idea to fix this attached in picture[image]

Comment: this is not same as in the picture and you're not using select box.

Comment: I take a screen shot part of it. Not whole page. Do you mean the code in the link ?

Comment: you say "If user selects a country" but there is no select box and something like json object.

Comment: I think you didn't read my previous sentence :) "My registration form has 2 step. Here is second step."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple css trick solved my problem.

```
<style>
    .form-group {
        height: 80px !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Remove float-left class and add parent row class -

<div class="row">
@if (@Model.StateList != null)
            {
                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                    <label asp-for="State"></label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateList, @Model.StateList, "- Please Select -",
                        new {@class = "form-control"})
                    <span asp-validation-for="State" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
                </div>
            }
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="City"></label>
                <input asp-for="City" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="City" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Phone"></label>
                <input asp-for="Phone" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Phone" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Company"></label>
                <input asp-for="Company" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Company" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="TaxId"></label>
                <input asp-for="TaxId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TaxId" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Gender"></label>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, @Model.GenderList, "- Please Select -",
                    new {@class = "form-control"})
                <span asp-validation-for="Gender" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="AboutJob"></label>
                <input asp-for="AboutJob" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="AboutJob" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="PostCode"></label>
                <input asp-for="PostCode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PostCode" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Town"></label>
                <input asp-for="Town" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Town" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Address"></label>
                <input asp-for="Address" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Address" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Celluar"></label>
                <input asp-for="Celluar" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Celluar" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="TaxOffice"></label>
                <input asp-for="TaxOffice" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TaxOffice" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="TaxAddress"></label>
                <input asp-for="TaxAddress" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="TaxAddress" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="FullName"></label>
                <input asp-for="FullName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="FullName" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Birthday"></label>
                <input asp-for="Birthday" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Birthday" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="CitizenId"></label>
                <input asp-for="CitizenId" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="CitizenId" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                <label asp-for="Website"></label>
                <input asp-for="Website" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Website" class="text-danger fixed-span"></span>
            </div>
</div>
```